# Overusing the App Delegate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, oop, uiapplicationdelegate

So, I'm rewriting an old application built by another developer - who is no longer part of our team.

What I have noticed is that in the AppDelegate there are the standard methods in there. On top of that there is also about another 30 other methods in there - from setting UI stuff to checking is things like T&Cs have been accepted - to showing items in a cart and even perfuming logouts and logins etc.

Now I am still new to iOS dev and I have been reading that abusing the app delegate isn't a great idea. Would this be considered as abuse?

Through out the application - the developer uses:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
```

Which I think is probably not the best approach?

If this is abusing the AppDelegate - how does one solve it - without using singletons?

I'm thinking of creating a new class and grouping the methods into relevance? So anything to do with setting items / checking etc - into one class. Then UI stuff could probably stay in the app delegate?

I think breaking this up will help with decoupling and dependancies. But is it the right way if most of the stuff in the App delegate is used to "Do" stuff and not store?

Comment: Why so afraid of singleton ? If you need an access to some data and method on every place in your application - singleton is the answer. Just use the greatest pattern ever right - stop being afraid of it :)

Comment: The singleton breaks SOILD principles though. Relying so heavily on one class is an issue I think.

Comment: I'd recommand to create a singleton class for this since they are lot of methods and other added variables and stuff.
If there was only one or two variables, I'd suggest to keep it in the AppDelegate (since it works, no need to modify it and do all the tests again), no need for creating a new singleton for so small staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about abusing part of the AppDelegate Class but in Programming prospective you should separate code into meaning full classes! Then it becomes easier to Manage.

Back to your problem! You can always create Singleton class also you can create category class for AppDelegate class So in a way you are separating the code.. Meaning if you have login/logout methods in delegate you can create Category called +UserManagement or Something and put all your code there! Also you can create AppUser Singleton class and put all the user management stuff there!

Comment: Yeah, I could create a singleton class - but the appDelegate is already a singleton class - and I think that's why it is used so much. I'm thinking of just creating custom classes that I can use to access certain methods that are needed. Like you suggested a user management class - but not have it as a singleton - if its job is just to do stuff - i probably don't need to store.. maybe the app delegate is the dirty silver bullet here... i just think it can be done better.

Comment: For sure! it all depends on the specs! Having singleton class has its own advantages.! again it depends on ur project and how the business model is.. personaly I like to have UserManagement as a Singleton class. Easy to manage! I strictly recommend you to separate the code asap!

Comment: The user management aside - there are methods in the for NSNotifications which I think is okay as those notification are for the whole app. There is also methods that handle status - like number of items in cart etc - which might be OK there, too? and since the application should b able to search - there is search methods there too - search is on more than one screen. The rest is UI stuff - which I probably won't be using in the redesign anyway?

Comment: NSNotifications can be triggered in anywhere in the app! Having separate class wouldn't stop you using them! If you are not comfortable with having separate class make a category class called +NotificationHandlers etc.

For shopping cart you can have Singleton too! there is only one shopping cart instance to be maintained throughout the app!

For search you can probably have Normal class.. UI Handling should be on respective view controllers!

Comment: Thanks that helps me a lot. What about Push Notifications - also in its own class - or is this the place for the AppDelegate as it would launch the application? Searching I will put into my own class and normal NSNotifications I will put into a class too - thee other stuff I will break up some more, too.

Comment: NSNotifications -  you should have push notification's delegate methods in in AppDelegate class. But again handling of tokens/Updating server etc can be separated! Thats how I have done!

Comment: But if I need to update the server with the new token - shouldn't this be when the app starts up - and thus, app delegate?

Comment: Obtaining Token is done in app delegate method but sending that to server can be done in Network class or somewhere else .. can't be ? its matter of calling network methods in app delegate class

Comment: I guess you're right there. I could bundle local and push notifications into a single class...since its the same thing (Just about?)

Comment: Yes! You just have to play with the code and you will find 1000 ways to do the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using AppDelegate as smelly code. 
Singletons are better but take in mind that they are hard to unit test.

Comment: Agreed, which is how I got to this question. I'm not planning on having loads of singletons. Thinking maybe one for user logging in / out - then another for the carts / watch list as thats really the same thing I think. the UI stuff will put put in the respective view controllers